# How to Disable Roslyn Language Services in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, roslyn

I have just installed new version of Visual Studio 2017 v15.8. There are 8 project in my application. When I try to open the solution, it takes 1 minutes(in older versions, it was taking 5-10 seconds). I tried to solve this problem by 3 different techniques according to my research but none of them solved my problem.

1. In "Manage Visual Studio Performance", I tried to disable Roslyn Language Service, but the disable button is disabled. I mean the disable button is gray. So it didn't work.
2. In Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> Advanced, there is a checkbox named "Enable full solution analysis. Tried to uncheck this but it was already unchecked. So I tried checking and again unchecking but it didn't work.
3. In Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> All Languages -> CodeLens, there is a checkbox named "Enable CodeLens". I unchecked this but my problem still exists.

So how can I disable Roslyn Language Services in Visual Studio 2017? Or is there another way that I dont have to disable it?

Comment: Why do you assume the delay is caused by Roslyn? Roslyn is the compiler used in VS 2017 since the day it came out. If you get a delay with v15.8 you should investigate what the *actual* problem is. It's highly unlikely that the same compiler went from 10" to 1 minute with a single update.

Comment: Sure you ahve a problem? Looks to me like Roslyn is dumping the old database and rebuilding - which then it will reuse later on futher restarts. A singel long load is not really bad.

Comment: Even if there was a problem with 15.8.0, the latest update is 15.8.8 which probably fixes the problem. Which version did you install? Did you check the known issues and fixes?

Comment: One thing that can cause delays is reopening documents that were open in a previous session. [This can be disabled in 15.8](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes#perf). SSIS packages for example can take a *lot* of time to open as they try to connect to their databases. Could it be that you left a "heavy" document open the last time you closed VS?

Comment: It is v15.8.5. I checked the known issues and fixes and didn't see anything about my problem.

Comment: This problem occurs for every time when I open my project. Even after restarting the operating system.

Comment: I have projects that take longer than that to finish loading, but it's always been that way with VS17.  Have you tried deleting the hidden `.vs` folder in the source directory?

Comment: I tried it after your advice but deleting .vs folder also didn't work.

Comment: It comes to my mind that I work offline. Maybe there is something trying to connect an online resource. Something similar happened in help window and I had figured out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try the solution in https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/320800/vs-1581-project-load-and-file-access-very-slow.html ?

I don't think it is because of Roslyn Language Service. Additionally, according to that link, you can upgrade your Visual Studio 2017 version to 15.8.7 or higher. It will probably solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

From [the Visual Studio Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/32190/cannot-disable-roslyn-language-service.html):

> The Roslyn Language Service is an essential service to VB & C# and cannot be disabled. The message is simply warning you that the service is taking longer than usual, so if you are experiencing performance problems, you can upload traces for us to investigate at that point via the feedback mechanism.

So it seems that disabling the RLS, will actually make your IDE like Notepad. Microsoft doesn't allow you to disable it. You can try to get the problem reproduced and fixed.

Comment: While I was using the older version of Visual Studio, loading the project doesn't take so much time. If Roslyn Language Service was also running in older version, there is another problem in current version. Am I wrong?

Comment: I am not a developer with the VS development team, so I can't say anything about the source of the problem. It might well be your virus scanner, a Windows update, etc.

Comment: How can I detect it? I can't check everything installed on my computer.